# Using mysql_connect in php 5.4.9 on ubuntu empties $_POST, Globals

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have the strangest problem - I've moved a complex PHP site over from Win 2008 to a linux box, and have found that when I POST to a page, and that page opens up a MySQL connection, the POST is emptied; in fact the entire $GLOBALS array empties.

Anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: Are you suggesting that `$GLOBALS` is non-empty prior to calling `mysql_connect()` and then empty immediately afterwards?

Comment: Hi eggyal, something like that. If I print_($GLOBALS) on the page without a mysql_connect (regardless of any query etc, JUST mysql_connect) then the globals array is empty. If I comment out that mysql_connect line, the array is full. The only difference between the two version fo the file is the mysql_connect.

Comment: Have finally tracked it down - it was actually a browser issue - only happens in Firefox. Will find specifics when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked in your Windows environment but not in the Linux environment, then it is most likely a configuration issue. A few **php.ini** settings you should check are:

- **post_max_size** - Should be large enough to handle the amount of data you are trying to post.

If using the Suhosin patch in your PHP build:

- **suhosin.post.max_vars** - Make sure this is large enough to handle data.
- **suhosin.request.max_vars** - Make sure this is large enough to handle data.

Also, I've seen in my own projects that sometimes Mod_Rewrite rules in an .htaccess file can be responsible for discarding variables, so make sure that isn't happening.

Comment: Nope they are all fine